# Using wp-load.php outside Wordpress. Security risk or not?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I am using this outside Wordpress to get access to different Wordpress' tables:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-load.php');
```

It works perfectly. But is there a higher security risk? Can I be hacked that way if e.g. someone knows the name of the php script?

I am not passing any values to the script. It's just called by cron to create pseudo materialized views out of some very slow MySQL views for statistical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `wp-load.php` via external .php file , there will be always one Security Issue on SQL injections. Someone can use or inject SQL queries if external file have not much secure.

You can always secure that file via giving right permission (644) , not leaving any extra spacing before and after code. Also do not put the file directly in the root , you can place that file outside root or inside wp-content.